# Using IN operator with a subquery

Tags: mysql, sql

Having the following scheme

```
CREATE TABLE request (
  `id` int,
  `classroom` varchar(255),
  `school` varchar(255),
  `date_of_application` datetime,
  `status` varchar(100),
  `user_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE user (
  `id` int,
  `full_name` varchar(255)
);

CREATE TABLE user_schools (
  `user_id` int,
  `schools_string` varchar(255) 
);
```

I need to obtain a list of requests where the status field is equal to 'pending' and where the school field is located in the list of schools associated with a user

Right now i am trying the following query

```
SELECT
  r.id,
  u.full_name,
  r.date_of_application,
  r.classroom
FROM
  request r
    inner join
  user u on u.id = r.user_id
WHERE
  r.school IN (
    SELECT
      us.schools_string
    FROM
      user_schools us
    WHERE
      us.user_id = u.id
  )
    AND  r.status = 'pending';
```

I currently get the total list of requests. I understand what is failing is the subquery.

Attached a [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/df575/1) to facilitate your collaboration

The result I expect are three applications where applicants are: user user, user user and another assistant user
Thanks for any idea. If there is a better solution, I thank you.

Regards

Comment: Why would you expect three rows?  One user "has" two class rooms and you are getting a separate row for each one.

Comment: You have to use `LEFT JOIN` instead of `WHERE` statement.

Comment: Could you please show how to implement the LEFT JOIN in this logic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is doing what you are asking.  If you want user/requests that are in the list, then you can use `select distinct` like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT u.full_name, r.date_of_application
FROM request r inner join
     user u
     on u.id = r.user_id
WHERE r.school IN (SELECT us.schools_string
                   FROM user_schools us
                   WHERE us.user_id = u.id 
                  ) AND
      r.status = 'pending';
```

But if you want the classroom and request id, then you are going to get your original result set (or some variation).

Comment: This do the job, But in this scenario I need to include the classroom field and id field in the final result

Comment: @user615274 . . . Then don't complain about the extra rows.  They have the information you want.

Comment: You are right, after checking my scenario I release i misunderstand my problem, thats why i describe it in the wrong way. For this case of use your answer is right.